# UART corrupted data

Tags: uart

I have connected a msp430 with a sensor via max3232 and I am able to see the incoming data. But the problem is that the 9 bytes of the data are ok but then the data get corrupted.
The baudrate I am using 9600 is the same the sensor uses If u connect it to the pc. 
If you can point me on what can be the error I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What does it means that the data is correct but then corrupted?

Comment: @clabacchio - the first 9 bytes are ok

Comment: @stevenvh may make sense, but it requires some effort to get that information from the sentence...

Comment: What are the first 9 bytes of data? What is the 10th? Do you use the same parity bit setting(Even, Odd or None) on both sides? Maybe it helps to use 2 stopbits (during debugging) at the transmitter side.

Comment: What are you using for the MSP430 clock?

Comment: where is the sensor data going?  the pc or msp430?  could you post the schematic and or code if possible.

Comment: That sort of symptom sounds like a buffer overrun problem.

Comment: How are you "looking at" the incoming data? is it feeding into a PC and viewing in HyperTerminal or something similar? A schematic and code example would really help. If it is hyper terminal though have you turned off flow control? (just a thought, I have never tried with it turned on)

Answer (score 2):

What is the max Baud Rate that works error free?

**Added:** I think that your UART function has an overrun; can you check?

RX ISR should be really short, something like this:

```
 #pragma vector=USCIAB1RX_VECTOR

  __interrupt void USCI1RX_ISR (void)
{
   char temp = UCA1RXBUF;
   if (pos < BUFFER_LEN) buffer[pos++] = temp;
   // Add call to intrinsic function to clear SR on exit, like _BIC_SR_IRQ(LPM3_BITS);
}
```

Then code in *main()* can watch the value of *pos* and the characters in the *buffer* to decide what to do.